# What is this sscanf doing?

Tags: c++

The code I'm working on is opening an uninitialized file and scanning in the following variables. I'm trying to figure out what it's doing, but I don't understand what the FSYM and ISYM formatting (?) is trying to do, other than perhaps declaring them as float or int strings.

```
sscanf(line, "%"ISYM" %"ISYM" %"ISYM" %"FSYM" %"FSYM" %"FSYM" %"FSYM" %"FSYM,
   &idummy, // nt   - skip
   &idummy, // l    - skip
   &idummy, // lev  - skip
   rad+nl,  // x    = radial coordinate
   vel+nl,  // xdot = radial velocity
   den+nl,  // rho  = density
   &dummy,  // tev  - skip temperature (eV)
   pre+nl   // p    = pressure
   );
```

line is the first line the opened file, which is then scanned in to the variables. Any ideas as to what's happening?

Comment: probably these are defines that evaluate to a string during compilation.

Comment: try to `printf` those

Answer (score 7):

Presumably, they are macros defined somewhere in your code, which expand to string literals containing the necessary specifiers for a `scanf` string. They would be something like

```
#define ISYM "d" // integer symbol for scanf
#define FSYM "f" // floating-point symbol for scanf
```

so that after expansion the argument becomes

```
"%""d"" %""d"" %""d"" %""f"" %""f"" %""f"" %""f"" %""f"
```

and, since consecutive string literals are joined to make a single string, this is equivalent to

```
"%d %d %d %f %f %f %f %f"
```

This might be useful if you might want to change the types:

```
#ifdef BIG_TYPES
    typedef long   i_type;
    typedef double f_type;
    #define ISYM "ld"
    #define FSYM "lf"
#else
    typedef int   i_type;
    typedef float f_type;
    #define ISYM "d"
    #define FSYM "f"
#endif
```

Of course, C++ has type-safe I/O to avoid all this nonsense:

```
std::istringstream ss(line);
ss >> idummy;
// and so on
```

Comment: or `ISYM` means "i symbol" and `FSYM` means "f symbol" aka `integer symbol` and `float symbol`

Comment: @0A0D: Yes, presumably they're short for "integer symbol" and "floating-point symbol".

Comment: You're correct, after greping around a bit I found them defined in another file. Turns out you were also right about their definitions for that matter.

Comment: I tend to use `std::istringstream` to extract stuff from a string. :)

Comment: @Pixelchemist: Me too. Unfortunately, my brain compiler is a bit buggy today.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Perhaps there is Braintellisense available (but it's prone to errors as well i guess...) :)

Answer (score 1):

That's preprocessor string concatenation.  They must be defined as strings somewhere else; when cpp hits multiple adjacent strings it concatenates them together, so the code is using the preprocessor to build a longer string from predefined parts.

Comment: That's not preprocessor string concatenation.

Comment: @NikBougalis: Yes it is. Or are you defining "preprocessing" to mean something other than "translation phases 1 to 6" (i.e. all the processing that comes before compilation)?

Comment: I'm defining preprocessor concatenation to be `A ## B` but that might be overly pedantic. Does the standard refer to the process of eliminating a closing double-quote, followed by whitespace, followed by another double quote as "concatenation"?

Comment: @NikBougalis: That's token concatenation (since `A` and `B` are preprocessor tokens but not necessarily string literals). The standard specifies phase 6 as "Adjacent string literal tokens are concatenated."

Comment: @MikeSeymour Thanks. I stand corrected. You learn something new every day.